# How to track youtube video which is present in anchor using google tag manager?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, youtube, google-tag-manager

My page consists of an anchor tag which includes a youtube video url.

I want to track how many times the video is played using Google Tag Manager.

Can someone please help me into this?

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{video_id}}">
```

Comment: video not present in iframe now it present in anchor tag so how I do that
?

Comment: Welcome to stack please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.   Show us what you have tried and any errors you have encountered.

Comment: Thanks, but please help me to above question?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of questions

1.) Is the video on the website or simple a link?

2.) Do you just want to track clicks on the play and not pull anything else like video title, percentage played etc?

You have a couple of solutions.

One if you want track all the video's information you can use a Youtube tracking script with GTM. There are a couple out there but here is a link to one: https://github.com/lunametrics/youtube-google-analytics/blob/master/lunametrics-youtube.gtm.js

You need to copy the code on github and place it into a custom HTML tag and set the triggers for that tag.

After this you need to create a event tag in GTM and then just set the Event Category, Action and Label.

You need to create a trigger also to fire on a custom event called "youTubeTrack"

So you have two tags

1.) One custom HTML which contains the YT script code

2.) One event tag which is what sends data to GA

Here is a screenshot of the Event tag

[image: Screenshot of Event tag set up]

And here is a screenshot of the trigger set up for that tag
[image: Screenshot of trigger setup]

Another solution if you only want to see if the video is clicked on.
You can create an event that fires each time the video link is clicked. Though it won't tell you if the person watch the video just that the linked was clicked.